# Why SOlite replacement not working?

Tags: android, sqlite

If I put the same comment(for example : "www.google.lv"), it's create this comment again. I want to this coment can't be duplicated, but is created the lastest.
I was include `insertWithOnConflict`, but it's not working.
There is my code:

```
    public class SQLiteAdapter {

public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "Content";

//create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
"create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
+ KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ KEY_CONTENT + " text not null);";

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

private Context context;

public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
context = c;
}

public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
return this;
}

public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
}

public void close(){
sqLiteHelper.close();
}

public long insert(String content){

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
return sqLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
}

public int deleteAll(){
return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
}

public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE,
            columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
      comments.add(comment);
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return comments;

  }
private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
    return comment;
  }
public List queueAll(){
String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT};
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
  null, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
  cursor.moveToNext();


return null;
}

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
  CursorFactory factory, int version) {
 super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

}

Comment: [Sigh]  What does not working mean?  Do we need to guess?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you misuse **insertWithOnConflict**. In your method **insert** you don't supply id column with ContentValues and thus **insertWithOnConflict** just adds another record with new id and existing Content. **insertWithOnConflict** would help in case you supply the id (your primary key) which already exists in the table.
In your case you should first find the id of the existing comment and then update it or insert a new one.

Comment: If I understand correctly his post, he wants the lastest insertion to get a new _id; therefore specifying the _id won't do it.  What he probably needs to do is to set up an Unique index on the column Content and use insertwithOnConflict so that the previous row will be deleted in case of a duplicate conflict.  However, I'm not familiar enough with the syntax of SQLite to show a proper example.

Comment: As far as I understood he needs to avoid comment duplicates and that's why he tries to use insertWithOnConflict. Yes, you're right, uniqie index on Comment field should do the trick.